# Replace number in one file with the number in other file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a problem. I have two files (file1 and file2). Both files contain number (with different values) which characterize same variable from different estimations. In file1 this number1 is for example in row beginning with name var1 in field $3, in file2 this number2 is in row beginning with name var2 and is in field $2.  I want take number1 from file1 and replace number2 in file2 with it. I tried following script, but it is not working, in output nothing is changed compared to original file2:

```
#! /bin/bash

    Var1=$(cat file1 | grep 'var1' | awk '{printf "%s", $3}' )

    Var2=$(cat file2 | grep 'var2' | awk '{printf "%s", $2}' )

    cat file2 | awk '{gsub(/'$Var2'/,'$Var1'); print}'
```

Thanks in advance!

Addition: For example, in file1 I have:

Tomato 2.154 3.789

Apple 1.458 3.578

Orange 2.487 4.045

In file2:

Banana 2.892

Apple 1.687

Mango 2.083

I want to change file2 so, that it would be:

Banana 2.892

Apple 3.578

Mango 2.083

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample of Input and sample of output in you post so that we could understand the question better.

Comment: can you add some samples of your input files please?

Comment: Thank You! I have added some example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this as `file1`:

```
var1 junk 101
var2 junk 102
var3 junk 103
```

And this as `file2`:

```
var1 201
var2 202
var3 203
```

This will extract field 3 from `file1` where field 1 is `var1`:

```
awk '$1=="var1"{print $3}' file1
101
```

This will replace field 2 in `file2` with `x` (101) where the first field is `var2`:

```
awk -v x=101 '$1=="var2"{$2=x}1' file2
var1 201
var2 101
var3 203
```

And combining them, you get:

```
awk -v x=$(awk '$1=="var1"{print $3}' file1) '$1=="var2"{$2=x}1' file2
var1 201
var2 101
var3 203
```

Assuming you want to overwrite the first file, you can do a conditional `mv` that runs only when things worked:

```
awk -v x=$(awk '$1=="var1"{print $3}' file1) '$1=="var2"{$2=x}1' file2 > /tmp/a && mv /tmp/a file2
```